# Var(X+Y) when Y is a subset of X

Tags: statistics

If for two dependent sets X and Y, Var(X+Y) = VarX+ VarY +2Cov(X,Y), how does the equation change if we assume that Y is a subset of X?

Comment: Variance is not defined on sets. It's defined on random variables.

Comment: @symplectomorphic It can be if you define a distribution on the set.

Comment: @symplectomorphic Please consider a practical example: a Profit and Loss(P&L) distribution of a portfolio X of several trading books such that one of the books is Y. Now P&L of Y is a random variable and so is the P&L of the entire portfolio.

Comment: User, in your "practical" example, $X=Y+Z$ where $Z$ is the P&L from all books except $Y$.  Then $Var(X+Y)=Var(2Y+Z)=4Var(Y)+Var(Z)+4Cov(Y,Z)$.  Without any information regarding the covariance of $Z$ with $Y$, this does not seem useful.